# invocationtargetexception during gson.fromJson()

Tags: android, reflection, gson

I'm writing a library which does a lot of stuff.

Situation:
in my android project AAA, I include the library  XXX  and derive from an abstract class A (which is located in the library XXX).

When I try to invoke the derived class in the library XXX, GSON doesn't find the class (in the debugger I can see the correct class - it was provided to the factory before)

Gson stops with an `InvocationTargetException` during resolve process. Exactly the same class does work if it is a part of the library XXX

JSON:

```
    {
      "subtext":"super subtext!!!",
      "myText":"hello 1",
      "id":"ff8081813cf34f79013cf34fba750001",
      "myAAA":false, 
      "version":0
    }
```

code:

```
  // code to invoke (in library XXX)
  public static A fromJson(String gsonString,
        Class clazz) {
    A myAbstractClass = null; // A1 is a subclass of A
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        myAbstractClass = gson.fromJson(gsonString, clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return myAbstractClass;

}
```

How can I solve this?

EDIT: stacktrace

```
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463): java.lang.StackOverflowError
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:371)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:355)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
02-19 17:58:24.442: E/AndroidRuntime(4463):     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:353)
```

Comment: which makes sense since XXX doesn't have any way of knowing about `? extends A1`

Comment: The class is given through a parameter.

Comment: don't you log the exception ? can you post the stacktrace ?

Comment: Try to invoke `clazz.newInstance()` and see if you actually can instantiate the class.

Comment: 'clazz.newInstance()' does work very well

Comment: That looks like an infinite recursion... Could you post a short excerpt of the json that is causing this?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565647/gson-2-2-2-causing-a-stackoverflow-on-4-2-1-only

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try... unfortunately it works perfectly if the class to instanciate is a part of the library... :(

Comment: downgrading the GSON lib was the workaround for this. Thanks! Mercutio, please log it as an answer then you will get the points