# Making GSON & Realm play nice

Tags: android, gson, realm

I'm trying to use Realm + GSON.
If they would work together well, it would be a match made in heaven.

However, when I extend my model objects with "extends RealmObject" I get this:

```
10-08 17:00:19.578  12492-12492/appwise.be.gsontestproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: appwise.be.gsontestproject, PID: 12492
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:372)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:356)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:128)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:75)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:358)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:109)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:46)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:84)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:83)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:75)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:358)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:109)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:46)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:84)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:83)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bin
```

Any fix available? :-)

Comment: It appears to be a bug in GSON. See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565647/gson-2-2-2-causing-a-stackoverflow-on-4-2-1-only?rq=1. We have experienced the same issue.

Comment: The downgrading trick to 1.7.1 works!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

U can do it like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
            return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            return false;
        }
    })
    .create();
```

`String json = "{ name : 'John', email : 'john@corporation.com' }";
User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);`

http://realm.io/docs/java/0.77.0/#gson

Comment: <3 absolutely perfect

Comment: @KillNono, You saved me a lot of time. Thanks!!

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfect.

Comment: Please note that this work around is not needed any more with Realm 1.0.0 and higher.
You can see that the current gson area has the exclusion policy hint already removed: https://realm.io/docs/java/1.0.0/#gson