# java.lang.StackOverflowError at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)

Tags: android, gson, realm, retrofit

I'm implementing "RealM" in my Android app. I'm getting JSON data by calling service with the help of "Retrofit library".

My Model Class is--

```
public class Game extends RealmObject
{
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("gameID")
    @PrimaryKey
    private int gameID;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("gameName")
    private String gameName;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("gameFormat")
    private String gameFormat;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("gameType")
    private String gameType;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("imageUrl")
    private String imageUrl;

    public Game() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Game(int gameID, String gameName, String gameFormat, String gamType, String imageUrl) {
        super();
        this.gameID = gameID;
        this.gameName = gameName;
        this.gameFormat = gameFormat;
        this.gameType = gamType;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public int getGameID() {
        return gameID;
    }

    public void setGameID(int gameID) {
        this.gameID = gameID;
    }

    public String getGameName() {
        return gameName;
    }

    public void setGameName(String gameName) {
        this.gameName = gameName;
    }

    public String getGameFormat() {
        return gameFormat;
    }

    public void setGameFormat(String gameFormat) {
        this.gameFormat = gameFormat;
    }

    public String getGameType() {
        return gameType;
    }

    public void setGameType(String gamType) {
        this.gameType = gamType;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Following is my OnfieldAPI interface to handle the request--

```
 public interface OnfieldAPI 
{

    Globals global=Globals.getInstance();
    String email=global.getUserName();

    @POST("games")
    Call<GamesResponse> getactivegames(@Header("authtoken") String authtoken);
}
```

And this is how I'm calling my web service to get Game response--

```
public void requestAllgames() {
        Globals globals = Globals.getInstance();
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Retrofit newRetro = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(globals.getBaseAddress())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        OnfieldAPI loginCheckApi = newRetro.create(OnfieldAPI.class);
        Call<GamesResponse> callPOST = loginCheckApi.getactivegames(globals.getToken());
        callPOST.enqueue(new Callback<GamesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GamesResponse> call, Response<GamesResponse> response) {

               // My Success code here.

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GamesResponse> call, Throwable t)
            {
                // My Failure Code Here
            }
        });
    }
```

Below is my "GamesResponse" class

```
public class GamesResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Integer status;
    @SerializedName("msg")
    @Expose
    private String msg;
    @SerializedName("payload")
    @Expose
    private List<Game> payload = new ArrayList<Game>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public GamesResponse() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param status
     * @param payload
     * @param msg
     */
    public GamesResponse(Integer status, String msg, List<Game> payload) {
        this.status = status;
        this.msg = msg;
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The status
     */
    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param status
     * The status
     */
    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The msg
     */
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param msg
     * The msg
     */
    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The payload
     */
    public List<Game> getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param payload
     * The payload
     */
    public void setPayload(List<Game> payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

But, when I run my app every time I'm getting following error. Below is my complete error log--

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)                                                                                at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:358)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:158)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTy
```

I googled this error but yet not reach to the solution, so any help for this issue will be really appreciated. Also let me know if I can provide more information for the same. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using an old version of Realm? In that case you need a custom type adapter as described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/0.88.0/#gson

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I'm using 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1' dependency

Comment: Then you need to add the custom ExclusionStrategy I linked to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making GSON & Realm play nice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260214/making-gson-realm-play-nice)

Comment: Why are you using 0.82.1? It's very very old, and nowhere near as stable as even 0.88.3, or more-so 1.1.1. Did you get your ideas from Ravi Tamada? That tutorial is worse than having no tutorials.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes I refereed Ravi Tamada's Tutorial. As I'm first time working on Realm, so don't have any clear idea on it. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @DnyaneshM you should refer to my tutorial, which I wrote primarily because of how bad Ravi Tamada's tutorial is: [Basics of Realm 1.2.0](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/basics-of-realm-a-guide-to-using-realm-1-2-0-634471c0fe8f#.vgmhkwn7q) and [a proper Realm example - Realm-Book-Example based on Ravi Tamada's tutorial](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions :

1.) update to a Realm version that is not ancient, such as 1.2.0

More info available on that in my tutorials/articles, also available on [`my profile page`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce?tab=profile):

- [Basics of Realm 1.2.0](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/basics-of-realm-a-guide-to-using-realm-1-2-0-634471c0fe8f#.vgmhkwn7q)
- [Realm-Book-Example based on Ravi Tamada's tutorial, rewritten for Realm 1.2.0 with heavily simplified code usage and proper structure](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-book-example)
- ["How to use Realm like a champ", with a lot of additional info on how to do and how not to do certain things with Realm](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149)
- [Designing the Schema of Realm effectively, and other Realm tips](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/designing-the-schema-of-realm-effectively-and-other-realm-tips-feb76c5b6072#.fxmu0jq9u)

2.) add this exclusion strategy

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
})
.create();
```

Comment: please let me know In which file do I add above code..?

Comment: Technically you need it where you create the `Gson` instance. You have `Gson gson = new Gson()` somewhere, and you should replace it with this.

Comment: First solution i.e. "1.) update to a Realm version that is not ancient, such as 1.2.0" worked for me.. I updated Realm version to 2.2.0.

Comment: I tend to recommend 1.2.0 over 2.x because the 2.x branch doesn't support Blackberry devices yet.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see this GameResponse class also.

I'm not 100% sure but in my opinion this is caused by extending RealmObject. Try to remove this inheritance for testing purposes and launch Retrofit request then. If everything will work then or you will some other exception (ex. parsing) we will be 100% sure that RealmObject is responsible for that.

Then you will need to have two separate classes : one for JSON representation and second for persistence using Realm. Of course you will need some mapper class then to convert JSON -> Realm and reverse.

**EDIT**

Other way (instead of mapping JSON representation class and RealmObject subclass) is to create your own TypeAdapters for GSON used in Retrofit (of course if you're using it). Some links for reference :

- https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/696
- https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#gson

Comment: @Pawal Urbal Yes u r right, this is happening because of extending RealmObject. For "GamesResponse" class plz check my updated question.

Comment: @DnyaneshM GameResponse class looks OK, I think it's not the problem here. So - you have to implement 2 layers - JSON and Realm and introduce mappers. Other way is to implement custom TypeAdapter for Gson used in Retrofit : https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/696 and https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#gson for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that it is happen during serialization.
Check this gist for proper setup: https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/ddac8efd018123a1e53a

Answer (score -2):

```
 public interface OnfieldAPI 
{
Globals global=Globals.getInstance();
String email=global.getUserName();
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("games")
Call<GamesResponse> getactivegames(@Header("authtoken") String authtoken);
}
```

just add

```
@FormUrlEncoded
```

Comment: He's not sending any parameters inside request body, only header. Adding @FormUrlEncoded will change nothing in that case.